# Proper use of an Outer Left Join

Tags: join

I want to return **ALL RECORDS** from the MillInvoice table regardless if there is a corresponding record in the PriceIncrease Table. When I run the query below I am getting just those records in the MillInvoice table that have a corresponding PriceIncrease record.

```sql
SELECT MILLInvoices.*,
       PriceIncrease.PriceIncreaseId,
       PriceIncrease.PriceForecasted,
       PriceIncrease.DateForecasted 
FROM MILLInvoices MILLInvoices
     LEFT OUTER JOIN PriceIncrease PriceIncrease
         ON MILLInvoices.MillCode = PriceIncrease.Plant
            AND MILLInvoices.ParentNumber = PriceIncrease.Mapa8
            AND MILLInvoices.Segment = PriceIncrease.GradeSegment
            AND MILLInvoices.City = PriceIncrease.City
            AND MILLInvoices.State = PriceIncrease.State
            AND MILLInvoices.Zip = PriceIncrease.ZipCode
```

Comment: Learn what left join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. Always know what inner join you want as part of a left join. Also this is a faq. Also please read & act on [mcve]. Including giving your SQL/DBMS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)

Comment: Please don't edit a question in a way that invalidates a reasonable answer. Although here your question was (& is) unclear so it shouldn't have been answered. Eg now that answer makes no sense. If there is a reasonable answer, edit your question to say what you were trying to say, and post a new question for the new question with new code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the tables or the data model looks like, but from your questions I'm guessing what you are trying to do here is to include records from `MILLInvoices` where no matching records in `PriceIncrease` exist. In this case the result will have empty fields under the columns that were retrieved from the table `PriceIncrease`. The query might be doing what you want until you get to the `WHERE` part. The `WHERE` part pretty much excludes any records from the result where columns from PriceIncrease have empty values or values that don't comply with conditions of the `WHERE` statement. Try removing the last part `WHERE` part if you want all `MILLInvoices` to appear in the result.

If you want row that match the criteria plus rows to which no corresponding records in `PriceIncrease` try something like this:

```
WHERE (PriceIncrease.BusinessUnit IS NULL AND PriceIncrease.PriceIncreaseNameId IS NULL) OR (PriceIncrease.BusinessUnit = 'Mill' AND PriceIncrease.PriceIncreaseNameId = 4)
```

Comment: So what happens now? You no longer need the WHERE caluse? does the new query work and gives you what you need? I also think there are too many join conditions, usually join condition are one field which is a primary key in one table and a foreign key in the other, but here I can identify two unnecessary conditions which are city and state. I would think this should be taken care of by zipcode. Can you give more information about the nature of both tables and the relationship between them?

Comment: Please don't answer unclear questions, ask for clarification, don't guess. Here is the classic result--another unclear question version & answer that doesn't make sense with it.

Comment: I saw a clear enough problem in the original question and I posted an answer. The fact that the OP changed the question to make the answer irrelevant is out of my control.